# Laravel: Undefined variable: posts (View: cant solve

Tags: laravel

So i have a problem that has been bugging me for a few days now. I want to display my posts on my homepage that is already displaying on my other pages. I think i have found why the information is not displaying and this is due to the Routes of the page. The view is looking fine and works correctly, however my controllers are the issue:

Web.php

```
 Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
 Route::get('/welcome', 'HomeController@index1');
 Route::get('/services', 'PageController@services');
 Route::get('/register', 'PageController@register');
 Route::get('/Create', 'PageController@Create');
 Route::get('/search', 'PageController@search');
 Route::get('/payment', 'PageController@Payment');

 Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
 Route::resource('search', 'SearchController');
 Route::resource('reviews', 'ReviewsController');
 Route::resource('postings', 'HomeController');
```

HomeController.php

```
    public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
public function index1()
{
    $postings = Post::all();
    return view('Pages.welcome', compact('postings'));
}
```

Welcome.blade.php

```
 @if(count($postings) > 1)
@foreach($postings as $post)
  <h2><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h2>
@endforeach

@else
  </p>no posts found</p>
@endif
```

The issue is in my WEB.PHP. PageController@index directs the page to the homepage, with HomeController being the controller that holds index. I then decided to create a function within that HomeController that allows me to display posts, however i keep getting error 'undefined error'. To conclude how would i insert a function in an existing controller that already has index.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers) in Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `$postings` variable in your view, don't access it. This does not mean you can not do what you want.

You can abuse how if statements are resolved. If you have `&&` operator in your if statement it will not check secondary conditions if first condition fails.

**Will fail**

```
@if ($postings)
```

**Will work**

```
@if (false && $postings)
```

To check if a variable is present without accessing it, you can use `isset()`, that is a `PHP` function. This will create the preferred statement that will not access `$postings` if it is not there. So try with the following code.

```
 @if(isset($postings) && count($postings) > 1)
     @foreach($postings as $post)
        <h2><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h2>
     @endforeach
 @else
     </p>no posts found</p>
 @endif
```

Comment: Okay i have now tried this and i get my page appearing, however i get the no posts found even tho there is posts in my database

Comment: But when you link to your home controller you dont include posts?     public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}

Comment: see i created a new function called index1 which should return the posts. I should see up to 4 posts on my page

Comment: Yeah so my blade file is welcome. My HomeController controls that page (obvs) there was a function called index already but i needed to create a new function so i called it index1 to display posts

Comment: how would i perform the dd$postings ? (sorry my laravel experience isnt great)

Comment: in index1 function before the view call dd($postings);

Comment: So i have done that, it stayed on the same page with the same 'no posts found' im sure its meant to go to a blank page right ?

Comment: Then something is completely wrong in your project, you are not calling index1 function dd kills the code and prints.

Comment: do i put the dd like so:     public function index1()
    {
        dd($postings);
        return view('Pages.welcome', compact('postings'));

Comment: and if your page load, you are not hitting the correct url

Comment: so are you saying it could potentially be my routes that are incorrect

Comment: are you able to take this to a discussions chat